# Como manter lista ordenada de registros em relacionamento N:N

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Considerando um cenário onde um **autor** pode realizar várias **publicações** e uma **publicação** pode possuir vários **autores**, temos uma tabela intermediária para manter os relacionamentos.

Entretanto, a ordem dos **autores** em uma **publicação** é escolhida pelo cliente no momento de *criação* ou *atualização* da **publicação**.

Nesse caso seria viável manter um atributo (por exemplo, JSON) na tabela de **publicação** para guardar as *chaves ordenadas* dos relacionamentos?

Como manter a ordem na lista de autores?

**EXEMPLO DE UM CASO**

O *usuario1* cria a *publicacao1* e relaciona à ela, além dele (que está relacionado automaticamente por ser o criador), os usuarios: *usuario2*, *usuario3* e *usuario4*.

Porém, ele deseja que os autores dessa publicação sejam mostrados na seguinte ordem: *usuario4*, *usuario1*, *usuario3* e *usuario2*.

Qualquer um dos autores pode alterar essa ordenação posteriormente.

Comment: você poderia postar a estrutura das tabelas existentes, e o que você deseja entre elas !?

Comment: @ThiagoFriedman A estrutura das tabelas é simples: `membro | publicacao | membro_publicacao`. O que eu desejo está descrito na questão: como posso manter uma determinada ordem na lista dos autores que estão relacionados com uma publicação?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown poderia explicar melhor como solucionar utilizando essa prática?

Comment: Esquece a sub-query, falei besteira. Seu caso acho que teria que salvar a ordem na tabela de relacionamento(intermediária), veja: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f2d256/5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apenas salve a ordem na tabela de relacionamento(intermediária), assim você sabe qual a ordem pra cada autor daquela publicação.

<kbd>**[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f2d256/5)**</kbd>